# Does $f(n,z)$ have $2^n$ distinct fixpoints $z$ for all $n$?

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations

Let $f(z)$ be a given degree $2$ polynomial.
Let $n$ be a positive integer.
Let $f(1,z) = f(z)$ and $f(n,z)= f(1,f(n-1,z))$.

How to decide if $f(n,z)$ has $2^n$ distinct fixpoints $z$ for all $n$ ?

Comment: Since $f$ is a function from $\mathbb N\times \mathbb C$ to $\mathbb C$, how do you define fixed points?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/795335/589 for a better notation.

Comment: @5xum I edited. Hope its clear now.

Comment: In the case $f(z)=z^2+z$ it is clear that $f(1,z)=z$ does not have two distinct solutions.

Comment: @David yes , but that does not settle the general case.
Suppose a given $f(z)$ has no fixpoints for the first 24 iterations (n = 1 .. 24) but it has for the 25th iteration.
How could that have been predicted ?

Comment: If $f$ is a polynomial, then all its iterates have fixed points, because of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.

Comment: @lhf yes ofcourse. Trivial.
I do not see how it helps.