# Is there official notation to represent "perform an operation n times"?

Tags: notation, recursion

I would like to know if you can represent the idea of say,

$$n^n$$

n amount of times without defining a function.  For example:

$$1$$
$$2^2$$
$$3^{3^3}$$
$$4^{4^{4^4}}$$
$$5^{5^{5^{5^5}}}$$

and so on, n amount of times.  Is there a way to represent this mathematically without defining a function?

EDIT: I understand that in this particular example the answer is tetration.  However, I am searching for more general notation that could also work with the following:

$$\ln(n)$$
$$n!$$
$${^n}n$$

all n amount of times.  Another example with factorial:

$$1!$$
$$(2!)!$$
$$((3!)!)!$$
$$(((4!)!)!)!$$
$$((((5!)!)!)!)!$$

Comment: see tetration..

Comment: Will that work for other operations, such as ln(n) n amount of times?

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration

Comment: the term is "iteration"

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795334/iterated-self-composition-of-arbitrary-function.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are looking for the notation for an [iterated function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Definition).  If $f$ is the function you want to iterate, you generally write
$$f^n$$
for the $n^\text{th}$ iterate of $f$.  (Notice that this is different from the notation for the $n^\text{th}$ derivative of $f$, which is given by $f^{(n)}$).  So, for example, you  could write
$$f(n) = n!$$
and then
$$f^1(n) = n!$$
$$f^2(n) = (n!)!$$
and so on.

Comment: Really? I've only seen $\ln^2 x \equiv (\ln x)^2$, and certainly $\sin^2 x \equiv (\sin x)^2$. I would interpret $f^2(n) \equiv (f(n))^2$ for the same reason.

Comment: @WChargin the trig functions are a notational exception. I haven't seen that used with logs myself.

Comment: Is there a way to represent this without defining a function?  So I could just write an expression?

Comment: @WChargin I wouldn't use the notation for a trigonometric function, since there $\cos^n(x) \equiv (\cos(x))^n$.  In fact, I'd probably be leery of using it for any function which gets its own notation (like $\ln$).  If you're in doubt when writing, you could say (for example) ". . . let $y_n = f^n(y_0)$, where $f^n$ denotes the $n^\text{th}$ iterate of $f$. . ." to make it clear.

Comment: @brandaemon I'm not aware of one (which doesn't mean it doesn't exist).

Comment: The notation in the answer is common. But there is a certain risk of clash of notations. If one wants to avoid this one can write $f^{\circ n}$

Comment: @brandaemon: People sometimes use $f^{\circ n}$ to distinguish from $f^n$ that is reserved for powers. This notation is perhaps not very beautiful, but it is flexible: if $\oplus$ is a binary operation, you can write $f^{\oplus n}$ to denote $\underbrace{f\oplus f\oplus \ldots \oplus f}_{n\text{ times}}$. P.S.: Didn't notice that quid had already said that.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/08/25/tricks-wiki-article-the-tensor-product-trick/) of the use of such notation. (Look for "define the tensor power").

Comment: I don't suppose there's anything particular for a function that's always iterated the amount of times as the operand?  For example, where $$f(n) = n!$$ but where the n in $$f^n$$ always equals that the operand (in this case the n in n!)?

Comment: @brandaemon I suppose you could define something like $g(n) = f^{n}(n)$.  Then, $g$ would be the function you want.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Strants' answer, which indeed gives the most common way of writing "do $f$ to an argument $n$ times", I'll give the "expanded form" of this which is $$f^n(x) \equiv f(f(\stackrel{(n)}{\cdots}f(x))$$

This is cumbersome and I strongly recommend using the compact notation, even if it means defining a new function. However it might suit your purposes for cases where the function has a reserved definition for the superscript (e.g. $\sin^2$), or you don't want to introduce a new function name. So for example, $$\sin(\sin(\stackrel{(n)}{\cdots}\sin(x)))$$

would apply the sine function $n$ times to $x$. However, take for example $$f(x) = \frac{2x+1}{x^2+e^x}$$

The $n$-iterated expression for it is (for me) unimaginable, and even if presented with it I would most likely not know at all what it was meant to designate. Of course, I could always write $f^n(x)$ and not have a doubt in the world :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use Knuth's up-arrow notation:

$a\uparrow n=a^n$

$a\uparrow \uparrow n=a^{a^{a^{\dots}}} $ n times

$a\uparrow \uparrow \uparrow n= a\uparrow \uparrow a\uparrow \uparrow a\uparrow \uparrow \dots$ n times

and in general

$a\uparrow ^b n=a\uparrow ^{b-1} a$ iterated n times

Comment: Is this only for exponents and tetration or can it work with other functions like logarithm and factorial?

Comment: This is used to extend exponentiation in a recursive way, I don't know if it could be used for other functions (probably not) but to represent big numbers you can use the so called Chained-arrow notation, sorry if it is only a partial answer but may it could be useful for you.