# $\log^2x$ = $(\log x)^2$ or $\log\log x$

Tags: notation, logarithms, function-and-relation-composition

When writing I found it a lot easier to say $\log^2x$ to mean $(\log x)^2$, but I didn't think about the ambiguity; because it is possible that can be interpreted as $\log\log x$.

My question is, what does $\log^2 x$ usually mean, or does it vary by source?

I'm trying to figure out whether it would be worth me getting in the habit of just avoiding the ambiguity completely.

Comment: Of course, $\log^2x$ should mean $\log\log x$, but in practice it's usually $(\log x)^2$ by analogy with the dreadful $\sin^2x$.

Comment: I've always seen it used as shorthand for $(\log x)^2$, never for $\log\log x$ (sometimes in number theory $\log_2 x$ is used for the latter, to save on space when writing many repeated logarithms). 

Nonetheless, I generally recommend getting into the habit of writing $(\log x)^2$ to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: No one writes that implying $\log \log(x)$. It’s always the square, no ambiguity there!
(At least in analysis. Anyway, it’s better with the parentesis)

Comment: See also [What does $\log^{2}{x}$ mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150546/what-does-log2x-mean) and [How to denote "powers" of a function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317708/how-to-denote-powers-of-a-function).